# Proving a sequence is bounded from above?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define the real sequence $(a_n)$ recursively as $a_0 = 1$ and $$ a_{n+1} = 3 - \frac{1}{a_n}. $$ I already proved by induction that this sequence is increasing, i.e. $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now I need to prove it is bounded from above. This means we have to find a $M \in \mathbb{R}^+ $ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n \leq M$. I'm not sure how to do this. I see that $$ a_n = 3 - \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} \leq M $$ if and only if $$ \frac{1}{3 - M} \geq a_{n-1} $$ but this doesn't really seem to help me. Do I need to find a particular $M$ to prove this?

Comment: Can $a_{n+1}$ be bigger than $3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the sequence is non-decreasing, $a_n \geq 1 > 0$ for all $n$. Therefore, $a_{n+1} = 3 -\frac{1}{a_n} \leq 3$ for all $n$.

Comment: Do you mean that, because $a_n \geq 1$, we have $1/a_n \leq 1$, and so $a_{n+1} = 3 - \frac{1}{a_n} \leq 3 - 1 = 2$? So should I pick $ M = 2$?

Comment: No, this would not work -- that would give $-\frac{1}{a_n} \geq -1$, while you want an upperbound. But you *can* use the fact that if $a_n > 0$, then $\frac{1}{a_n} > 0$, and thus $-\frac{1}{a_n} < 0$ (so you subtract something positive to $3$ -- the result is less than $3$)

Comment: No, if $\alpha<1$ is it not true that $3-\alpha<3-1$. @Kamil

Answer (score 2):

If $a_n>3$ then $a_{n+1}<3$. As you already know that $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$, this is absurd.

Comment: Thanks. That is actually very logical. Do you know what the limit of this sequence is? I solved the quadratic formula $L = 3 - \frac{1}{L}$, i.e. $L^2 - 3L + 1 = 0$, but this gives me two limits? One for plus and one for minus sign?

Comment: @Kamil You have two solutions, both in $(0,3)$; one is $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}< 1$, the other $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}>1$. Since $a_0=1$ and the sequence is non-decreasing, only one of them can be correct...